# Android: Not end (finish) the last task in stack

Tags: android, task, back-button, kill, activity-finish

I would like to know if there is a way to prevent the last task in the Android Task Stack from being finish(); if the user clicks the back button. I do like that the user is sent back to the Home Screen but I would like the last activity to remain in the stack so if the user clicks on the app launcher from the home screen again it doesn't start the main activity again with a new task stack. My app requires the users to sign in and out of it so if they do sign out I want the task stack to be cleared. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is partially possible changing the implementation of your application as a background `Service`. Of course, preventing your application from being closed is a very bad practice, actually anything that restricts users from closing an app is a bad practice. As said before, the best way to implement this is putting it within a Service, but this way you should implement at least one mechanism to cleanly close your app (an exit button, for instance), otherwise your users will be in need to force your app to close (and that you won't be able to prevent).

More on this, [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html).